# How to pass array to sheets (Getting error on passing array to sheet)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a code that is taking values from a range C2:I and joining the values into one.
At the beginning I have multidimensional array but after joining it it becomes one dimensional.

At the end I want to pass the result to Column J and here I am getting an error

`Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.`

I am using the method I have always used and I have no idea why it is not working now...
Do you think it is because the original range has almost 150k rows?

here is a code I have now:

```
function laczenie() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("部品仕入先");
  var rng = ws.getRange(2, 3, ws.getLastRow(), 7).getValues();

var final = [];
  //Logger.log(rng);

  var filtered = rng.map(x => {
  return x.filter(j => j)
})
        //Logger.log(filtered);

 for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
       final.push(filtered[i].join("・"));
    }
  //Logger.log(final);
//ws.getRange("I2").setValue(final[3]);

//pass data to J column

//ws.getRange(2, 10, final.length + 1, 1).setValues(final);
//ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 10, final.length, 1).setValues(final);
ws.getRange(2,1, final.length, final.length).setValues(final);
}
```

As you can see I have already tried 3 different ways  to pass the data and always the same error

the above setValue works perfect but setValues is getting an error

Any advice help will be appreciated!
Regards
Timonek

Comment: while using the `setValues`, the dimension should be matched. Means, number of column should match.

Comment: thanks! I have changed that final 1D array to 2D array and it seems to be working but now I am getting timeout error so I guess it is only passing some part of an array

Comment: That seems to be a different issue. Hope you already working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the `setValues`, the dimension should be matched. Means, number of column should match.